# While loop inside a For loop not working for string matching

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, string-matching

I have the following scenario:

I'm trying to see if a particular file name exists in a list of file name. However, if the file does not exist, I want to modify the non matching elements of my string by other strings until the desired file name matches with any file name in the list. In order to do that, I decided to split my desired file name in different components and add them to the string; so, it will be easier for me to identify the non matching components.
My code is the following:

```
# Define the components of the file name to be match
filename_components = ['p', '2500', '_g', '-1.0', '_m', '0.0', '_t', '00', '_', 'st', '_z', '-5.00', '_a', '+0.40', '_c+0.00_n+0.00_o', '+0.40', '_r+0.00_s+0.00.mod']

# Import the text file containing the list of file names
file_names = open('files_list.txt', 'r').read()

file_name = filename_components[0]

# Iterate over all the file components to match them with the file list
for n in range(len(filename_components)):

    # If the file name exists, add the next component
    if file_name in file_names:
        print(f'File name: {file_name} is matching! Adding {filename_components[n+1])
        file_name += filename_components[n+1]

    # While the file name does not match, perform a swap of the component until the file name matches
    while file_name not in file_names:
        print(f'{file_name} not matched')
        '''
        some code that swaps the components
        .
        .
        .
        '''
        file_name += filename_components[n+1]

        # If the file name matches with the swapped component, break the while loop
        if file_name in file_names: break
```

If I run this code, I get this output:

```
File name: p is matching! Adding 2500
File name: p2500 is matching! Adding _g
File name: p2500_g is matching! Adding -1.0
p2500_g-1.0 not matched 
p2500_g+0.0 not matched 
p2500_g+1.0 not matched 
p2500_g+2.0 not matched 
File name: p2500_g+3.0 is matching! Adding _m        
File name: p2500_g+3.0_m is matching! Adding 0.0        
File name: p2500_g+3.0_m0.0 is matching! Adding _t        
File name: p2500_g+3.0_m0.0_t is matching! Adding 00        
File name: p2500_g+3.0_m0.0_t00 is matching! Adding _        
File name: p2500_g+3.0_m0.0_t00_ is matching! Adding st        
File name: p2500_g+3.0_m0.0_t00_st is matching! Adding _z        
File name: p2500_g+3.0_m0.0_t00_st_z is matching! Adding -5.00
```

At this point, I know that adding this -5.00 component to the string is not going to match because I tested it myself. Therefore, I expect my while loop to be called. However, the matching conditional was not met, neither the not matching conditional. I placed a print statement ouside the while loop and within the main For loop to make sure the for loop was still working and it does, it iterates over the remaining components of the list. But, no more components are being added to the string and neither the if or the while loop conditions are met. My expected result at the end, if everything works correctly should be:

```
File name: ....mod is matching!
```

I know eventually I'll run into an IndexError, but I know how to fix that. I just need help to understund, why is my while loop not working for the rest of the iterations?

Comment: `file_names = open('files_list.txt', 'r').read()`: this will read the whole file as a single string, including newlines. Assuming your filenames in the file are separated by newlines, is that the way you want to read your `files_list.txt` file?

Comment: You probably want to (a) separate the lines, (b) strip the newlines (and probably any leading/trailing whitespace), and (c) close the file after finishing with it.

Comment: The rest of the program has similar level of problems; you need to go through it carefully and check what each line is doing, perhaps with a combination of `print` statements and some of the techniques from the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code

- Firstly, for reading the `file_names` variable, you probably want to (a) separate the lines, (b) strip the newlines (and probably any leading/trailing whitespace), and (c) close the file after finishing with it.

  Something like:

  ```
  with open('files_list.txt', 'r') as fh:
    file_names = [line.strip() for line in fh]
  ```

  - The `with` statement makes sure the file is closed
  - The `.strip()` removes the newlines and any leading/trailing spaces
  - The `for line in fh` loops through the file line-by-line; enclosing it in a `[...]` like this turns the result directly into a list
- It's not clear what you're intending with the `for n in range(len(filename_components))` loop; most likely, you don't want to use `n` t all here, and instead loop through the components:

  ```
  for filename_component in filename_components:
      ...  # handle each filename_component
  ```
- In a loop like `while file_name not in file_names`, you do not need a separate `if file_name in file_names: break` at the end; possibly you don't want the `while file_name not in file_names` at all and instead you're intending to break out of the outer `for` loop?
- More generally, a couple of techniques to develop programs like this:

  - Write the code piece by piece, using `print` statements to make sure each part is working as it should.
  - Have a read through the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide and see if some of the techniques help.